# Issue with dynamic variables in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer like always however this time instead of a static email like below which is working fine:

```
$mail->AddAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
```

I want to use:

```
$mail->AddAddress(".$email.");
```

But I face below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address: '.myemail@gmail.com.' in /var/www/html/project/process/class.phpmailer.php:774 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/project/process/class.phpmailer.php(711): PHPMailer->addAnAddress('to', '.myemail@gmail.com', '') #1 /var/www/html/project/process/process.php(45): PHPMailer->addAddress('.myemail@gmail.com') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/project/process/class.phpmailer.php on line 774
```

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: While I'm unfamiliar with phpmailer, is there any reason why you can't just do `$mail->AddAddress($email, 'my name');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your .'s inside the quotation marks. If your just wanting to add the email address then just do $mail->AddAddress($email). If for some reason you want to have the email address quoted, and I'm not sure phpmailer will accept this you would using something like $mail->AddAddress('"'.$email.'"');

Comment: As you mentioned it works file if use  $mail->AddAddress($email). However I was using quotes to add a title for it for example AddAddress('"'.$email.'"', 'my name'); Unfortunately your suggestion with quotes is still not working and gives the same error.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but to add an email address with an associated name, the function call is $mail->AddAddress($email,"myname"); if your hardcoding a name or $mail->AddAddress($myEmail,$myName); assuming the email address is in $myEmail and the person's name is in $myName. To my knowledge you cannot do $mail->AddAddress($myEmail) where $myEmail contains both the email address and the name.

Comment: Just as a quick reference here is the link to the phpMailer Methods :http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods

Comment: Yes, as you suggested $mail->AddAddress($email,"myname"); will work just fine. My misunderstanding was that I was adding quotes around the $email. Thank you mate!

Comment: @Jim_M, please don't link to obsolete documentation. Current docs are here: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html